# Improve performance of a BETWEEN join

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have a currency exchange rate table `MngCurrencyRate`:

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[MngCurrencyRate](
    [DwDimCurrencyRatePk] [int] IDENTITY(0,1) NOT NULL,
    [currencyRef] [int] NOT NULL,
    [FromDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ToDate] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [UsdRate] [numeric](19, 6) NOT NULL,
    [EuroRate] [numeric](19, 6) NOT NULL
) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It has data of the form:

```
currencyRef FromDate    ToDate  UsdRate EuroRate
44  2020-02-01 00:00:00.000 2020-02-02 00:00:00.000 0.013986    0.012606
44  2020-02-02 00:00:00.000 2020-02-03 00:00:00.000 0.013986    0.012608
44  2020-02-03 00:00:00.000 2020-02-04 00:00:00.000 0.014028    0.012684
44  2020-02-04 00:00:00.000 2020-02-05 00:00:00.000 0.014065    0.012735
44  2020-02-05 00:00:00.000 2020-02-06 00:00:00.000 0.014046    0.012771
44  2020-02-06 00:00:00.000 2020-02-07 00:00:00.000 0.014025    0.012772
```

It has a clustered columnstore index, as well as this one:

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [Ix_MngCurrencyRate_CurrencyRef_Dates] ON [dbo].[MngCurrencyRate]
(
    [currencyRef] ASC,
    [FromDate] ASC,
    [ToDate] ASC
)
INCLUDE (   [DwDimCurrencyRatePk],
    [UsdRate],
    [EuroRate]) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
GO
```

It has in it 109,934 records, and it grows by ~30 records per day.

Every join to this table (and there are many throughout my ETL process) is of the form:

```sql
declare @fromDate datetime = '2020-01-01';

select
    Preservation.UserRef,
    Preservation.CurrencyRef,
    Preservation.Amount as AmountUserCurrency,
    Preservation.Amount * MngCurrencyRate.UsdRate as AmountUSD,
    Preservation.Amount * MngCurrencyRate.EuroRate as AmountEUR
from
    Preservation
    inner join
    MngCurrencyRate
        on (Preservation.CurrencyRef = MngCurrencyRate.currencyRef
            and Preservation.DateCreated >= MngCurrencyRate.FromDate
            and Preservation.DateCreated < MngCurrencyRate.ToDate
            )
where
    DatePreservationReleased >= @fromDate
```

If I run this query just on the Preservation table, without joining to MngCurrecyRate, the query returns 681,550 records in 5 seconds. When joining on MngCurrencyRate, it takes 20 seconds to get the same 681,550 records.

The join on >= and < causes queries to take far longer than a parity join (=).
For the sake of testing, I changed the join to

```sql
        on (Preservation.CurrencyRef = MngCurrencyRate.currencyRef
            and MngCurrencyRate.ToDate = '9000-12-31' --latest record per currency
            )
```

and it returned the same 681,550 in 5 seconds.

Comparing the estimated execution plans of the two queries, the second one takes 1% of the load, while the one I actually need consumes 99%.

Both estimated execution plans can be viewed here:
https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=By8JZOkLI

Is there anything I can do, either in the join or in the structure of my data, to improve the performance of these queries?

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: What makes you say that it takes far longer? Can you post explain plan as well?

Comment: Not an answer because your question needs more detail, but you probably would get a speedup if you have an index on `MngCurrencyRate (currencyRef, FromDate, ToDate)`.

Comment: Can you provide DDL (Create Table) statements for the table and all indexes?

Comment: You already have a few requests for information (DDL , execution plan) please add to it the cardinality (number of rows) of each tables,  min/avg/max records in MngCurrencyRate per currencyRef and current execution time.

Comment: I hope the info I added in the post is sufficient.

Comment: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/ for sharing SQL Server execution plans online

Comment: Still missing the demography of currencyRef

Comment: I edited the post, execution plan now on BretOzer's (cool option, thanks!).

Comment: What do you mean with regard to the demography? There are ~30 currencies, each one has a new record added pretty much once a day.

Answer (score 0):

An index on `Preservation` has a good chance to improve the performance

```
create index Preservation_CurrencyRef_DateCreated_idx on Preservation (CurrencyRef, DateCreated)
```

Comment: Did you have a chance to try it?